# Is R.layout.listview is same as R.id.listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-resources

I am new to android programming. I have created a `ListView` and its `android:id="@+id/listView1"`

```
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.listView1);
```

Will it refer the same ListView? Are there any difference between these two snippets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***No Both are different.***

***R.id.listView1 :-***

Represents the id of View which is declared in layout (your XML file) as `android:id="@+id/listView1"`

and

***R.layout.listView1 :-***

Represents the layout file (xml file) which into `res -> layout` dir

---

You can do

```
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

because ListView is of View family.

But you can't do

```
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.listView1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:id="@+id/listView1"
```

this may be id of the listview created by you in the xml file.

```
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

and ou are representing the listview in your java file by calling the id.

```
ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.listView1);
```

this is the way of representing a layout in your java file by calling the id of the layout

Answer (score 0):

Both are representing different means.

```
android:id="@+id/listView1"
```

represent an widget inside an layout (XML file) that have Attribute as follows :-

```
android:id="@+id/listView1"
```

where as `R.layout.listView1` shows you have a `XML` file in your layout folder named as `listView1`.

so both are different.